# Creating a hierarchical dropdown list from a sharepoint list

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm trying to take data from a SharePoint list that is of the form:
ID, Title, Parent_ID, some other stuff that isn't of consequence.

> ```
> 1, GroupA, null  
> 2, GroupB, null  
> 3, GroupC, null  
> 4, ASubA, 1  
> 5, ASubB, 1  
> 6, BSubA, 2  
> 7, CSubA, 3  
> 8, CSubB, 3  
> 9, CSubC, 3
> ```

I want to translate this cleanly to a dropdown on a webpart that would look like:

> Show All
>    GroupA
>     ASubA
>     ASubB
>    GroupB
>     BSubA
>    GroupC
>     CSubA
>     CSubB
>     CSubC

I can throw this together with some recursion and some DataTable merging, but it will be confusing and more difficult to maintain for the next person who comes along. I'm looking for a smooth way of accomplishing this. I feel like I should be able to accomplish this with some GroupBy in a CAML Query, but I haven't been doing SharePoint for too long.

Is there some hierarchical data structure I could stick this all into, and then pull it back out in order? Or some Query Syntax that I'm not thinking of?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The list really only has to go two deep, so I just ended up doing a simple for loop and some datatable.import and datatable.merge to construct a fresh data table to return from my data access object.  I just figured that there would be some way to do it in the query statement with the data I already had.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a Parent_ID, why don't you use a Group_ID:

1, GroupA, 1
2, GroupB, 2
3, GroupC, 3
4, ASubA, 1
5, ASubB, 1
6, BSubA, 2
7, CSubA, 3
8, CSubB, 3
9, CSubC, 3

You can now sort by Group_ID in your query.

Alternately, you could use two lists, one for groups, and the second for subs with a lookup column.

Comment: Don't want to change any of the data in the lists. You're right though, this would have worked if this was how it was originally designed.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of SharePoint are you using? If you are using SharePoint 2010, instead of creating your own, I would recommend using [Managed Metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee559337.aspx):

> Managed metadata is a hierarchical collection of centrally managed terms that you can define, and then use as attributes for items in Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea: merge columns 3 and 1, and sort by the resulting value
GroupA, 1
ASubA, 14
ASubB, 15
GroupB, 2
BSubA, 26
GroupC, 3
CSubA, 37
CSubB, 38
CSubC, 39
(Alphabetical sorting on numbers)

Of course, you'll need to insert some zeros if you have a longer list.